# cant get google maps on eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android application on eclipse and have looked around but I still can't get the map on, I have the asked add-on but maps aren't on it, can anyone help

Comment: This might help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your android SDK contains Google API. If not download it. This might help  https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing . After installing just go through the link  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android .It is very useful. After that if you have any doubts , just post here..